# How to prevent unauthorized users from seeing information on a page in React web application

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I am learning front-end and back-end using React and Node.js/express. I have a question on a security issue. Lets say i want to display certain information on a page based on user role. Since it is possible to manipulate the state of react app using browser tools such as react devtools, how can i prevent users from doing so and being able to see information that they should not be able to see?

Below i provided a simple code to represent what i mean:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Navbar() {
  const [role, setRole] = useState('guest');

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUserRole() {
      const response = await fetch('/api/user/role');
      const { role } = await response.json();
      setRole(role);
    }

    fetchUserRole();
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        {role === 'admin' && (
          <li>
            <Link to="/admin">Admin</Link>
          </li>
        )}
        {role !== 'guest' && (
          <li>
            <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
          </li>
        )}
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

It is just a dummy code generated by chatGPT to display the question that i have: users would be able to change the "role" state using browser tools and in return see links that they should not be able to see otherwise. Now i realise that i should always check for authorization on the server-side when user tries to navigate to other page, but is it possible to prevent user from SEEING these links even if he tampers with the "role"?

I was not able to come to a solution on how to prevent users from seeing unauthorized content.

Answer (score 0):

### I believe a json web token is what you are looking for, but first some information:

First things first. The only way to actually secure data that you don't want the user to see is to have a backend server running. You then can validate the user (via a json web token) and then send the data from an external backend API. You would then fetch that API endpoint from the front end. If it's not a big deal that the user sees the information you are trying to hide it can be done from the front end, but I am not sure which situation applies to you based on your question. If thsi data truely shouldn't be seen by regular users you need to authenticate them via json web token (*also known as JWT for short*)